# mysql select with this query then pad out with this query?

Tags: mysql, select, union

I am trying to do a mysql query to select some news stories from a table, now the key is I always need 5 results.

so I was hoping to be able to pad out my results with another where clause ie

```
select * from here where this = 1
if there is < 5 results then select * from here where this = 2
limit [how ever many we are short say the first query brings back 3 results this should bring back 2]
```

Now I've looked at using a union to do this but without outside help ie from php and another query to count the results I don't think it is possible, I know I could simply use php to do this, and will probably end up doing that, but I was just wondering if what I am trying to do is possible with one mysql query?

EDIT:

also it needs to order by date but they are not really posted in order so

order by date get upto 5 where this = 1 and if there isn't 5 pad it out with the remainder of where this = 2 also ordered by date.

Another Shameful Edit:

ask a silly question lol... it was my sleep deprivation I just assumed there was data in the table and the previous coder was using unions to do all sorts of stuff, making me think it was more complex than it should be

```
SELECT *
FROM
 news
WHERE
 ( this = 45 || this= 0 )
AND
 active =  '1'
ORDER BY
 this ASC,
 date_added DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Comment: If our queries are not returning what you are looking for please explain what is wrong with their results.

Comment: ask a silly question lol... it was my sleep deprivation I just assumed there was data in the table and the previous coder was using unions to do all sorts of stuff, making me think it was more complex than it should be

SELECT *
FROM
news
WHERE
( this = 45 || this= 0 )
AND
active =  '1'
ORDER BY
this ASC,
date_added DESC
LIMIT 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about -

```
SELECT *
FROM here
WHERE this < 5 -- added this WHERE clause based on the idea that there will be at least one item per this
ORDER BY this ASC, `date` ASC
LIMIT 5;
```

Or are you after the five results then being sorted by date again -

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM here
    WHERE this < 5 -- added this WHERE clause based on the idea that there will be at least one item per this
    ORDER BY this ASC, `date` ASC
    LIMIT 5
) AS tmp
ORDER BY `date` ASC
```

Comment: is a nice thought lol, but I need to get 5 where x = 1 and if there isn't 5 there say there is just 2 of them I need to get 3 where x = 2

they are also ordered by date so if I did

    SELECT * FROM here WHERE ( x = 1 || x = 2 ) ORDER BY date ASC

then it would return x = 2 ones first and I only want to pad it with these if there isn't enough x = 1

      SELECT * FROM here WHERE ( x = 1 || x = 2 ) ORDER BY x ASC, date ASC 

doesn't seem to work either

Comment: My query (and @ManseUK's) will both satisfy your original question. If you want it to do something else you need to update your question with a better explanation of what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You could combine the where clauses and use limit :

```
select * FROM here WHERE this = 1 OR this = 2 ORDER BY this LIMIT 5
```

Even in there were 15 records where `this` is equal to `1` this would only bring back 5 records ...

Comment: You'd want an `ORDER BY` to make sure that you get the results from `WHERE this = 1` first.